# Bad value http://www.science%20channel.com/ for attribute href on element a: Invalid host: Illegal character in domain: space is not allowed

Tags: html, href, space, w3c-validation

I got this message while validating my website:

> Bad value `http://www.science%20channel.com/` for attribute `href` on element `a`: Invalid host: Illegal character in domain: space is not allowed

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.science%20channel.com/">Science Channel</a>
```

Can someone please find a solution to this problem?

Comment: The message tells you that a space for a host name (domain) is invalid. `%20` is a space so use the correct character instead of `%20`. If the domain is `sciencechannel.com`  then don't add a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

A Url is not allowed to have a space. `%20`

if your URL is http://www.science-channel.com then try

```
<a href="http://www.science-channel.com/">Science Channel</a>
```